Comparing two identical surveys with different samples sizes and response levels
Silly question, but my mind has gone blank. I’m trying to undertake a simple comparison between two samples (organisational performance) using an online survey. To obtain a CI of 80% with a margin of error of 10%, I need 31 and 35 responses respectively. I obtained this, but had then had to discard some erroneous submissions, which take it slightly below the required level. What would you do in this case? Also, should I be trying to account for the difference in response rate?
Category                 Sample 1        Sample 2
Population               110             210
Responses required @80% CI & 10% margin of error    31  35
Responses received  34  41
Response rate       30% 20%
Viable responses    27  34

